# Disabling VML support in HTMLDocument parser

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, vml, ihtmldocument2

I am parsing and massaging existing HTML files created by Word (the files cannot be recreated). The HTML files with embedded images include conditional formatting for the vml enabled browsers similar to the following:

```
     <!--[if gte vml 1]>
     <v:shape
     id="_x0000_i1042" type="#_x0000_t75" style='width:24pt;height:24pt'>
     <v:imagedata src="test_files/image002.png" o:title="Text-HighlightColor-icon_32x32"/>
    </v:shape>
    <![endif]-->
    <![if !vml]>
    <img width=32 height=32 src="test_files/image002.png" v:shapes="_x0000_i1042">
    <![endif]>
```

I load the HTML file into an instance of the `IHTMLDocument2` object. Since IE supports VML, it parses out the `<img>` tag above leaving only `shape` and `imagedata` tags. I would prefer to ignore all vml specific tags and work only with the `<img>` tag.

Is there any way to disable the VML support (similar to `IHTMLDocument2.desgnMode = "On"` to disable scripts) programmatically?

Comment: Can you try what's described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753685.aspx : add a `#default#VML#` DWORD key with a value of 0 to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AllowedBehaviors`

Comment: @Simon Mourier - #default#VML# already exists with the value of 0. Deleting it or changing to 1 does nto make any difference unfortunately...

Comment: Have you checked the 32-bit equivalent also (HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\...) ? Otherwise can you try to modify HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector\VML to 0.9 for example (on my 64-bit machine, iexplore apparently runs 32-bit somehow and checks the WOW6432Node node...)

Comment: #default#VML# is 0 in Wow6432Node as well :-(

Comment: Have you tried the other key?

Comment: Aha! Setting VML to 0.9 caused the first condition (if gte vml 1) to be skipped, but :"vml" was still defined, so I ended up with no images at all. But deleting/renaming the vml key (so that now it is null), caused the second condition (if !vml) to become true. The only problem is that the registry key is in HKLM, but I should be able to deal with that (registry redirection or registry API patching). Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Word generates is called ["Conditional comments"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx). More specifically, we have here "Downlevel-hidden conditional comments" which take the following form:

```
<!--[if expression]> HTML <![endif]-->
```

The `expression` uses operators and ["Version vectors"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx#Version_Vectors). 
In general, these vectors refer to "IE" and are used to handle [HTML compatiblity issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817577.aspx).

But you can use custom version vectors:

> If you develop add-ons, you can use custom version vectors to provide
>   version information to webpages. To define a custom version vector,
>   add a REG_SZ value to the Version Vector Registry key. The name of the
>   new key defines the feature value to use in a conditional comment, as
>   shown here.
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>    Software
>       Microsoft
>          Internet Explorer
>             Version Vector
>                Contoso = 0.9
> ```
>
> The previous example uses a custom version vector to indicate that a
>   pre-release version (0.9) of the fictional Contoso control is
>   installed on a user's computer. This next example shows how a
>   conditional comment might use this information.
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt Contoso 2]>
> <p>Your version of the Contoso control is out of date; Please update to the latest.</p>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Since VML is itself an (embedded) add-on, you can play with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector\VML` key and/or the 32-bit one on a 64-bit OS `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector\VML`. Apparently, completely deleting the key fixed your problem.